# Reverse SSH tunnel with AutoSSH

Tags: ssh-tunneling, autossh

How to apply dynamic port allocation in AutoSSH?
In the remote device using ssh we make a reverse tunnel by this command:
`ssh -f -N -R 0:localhost:22 username@ip`

It allocates a dynamic port on the server and prints that port on the machine . I want to apply the same thing using autossh.

So my question how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`autossh` is a drop-in replacement for `ssh` with one caveat. *Drop-in replacement* means you call it instead of `ssh`, passing exactly the same arguments as with `ssh`. The caveat is that `autossh` has a mandatory option (*oxymoron alert!*) that you must also include in your command invocation.

The required `autossh` option is `-M port` where *port* is the number of an unused port on your system such that *port+1* is also unused. The `autossh` manpage uses ports `20000` and `20001` as an example. Since those are both free on my system I use those as well so I add `-M 20000` to my `autossh` calls.

If you use the same ports your command will be:

```
autossh -M 20000 -f -N -R 0:localhost:22 username@ip
```

FYI these ports are used to monitor availability of the remote. Test data is sent out on `20000` and returned on `20001`. If nothing is returned then `autossh` tries to reestablish a connection (that's simplifying things a bit but you get the point).